# Manually update IndexedEmbedded after return view from controller

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

Reffering to Hibernate Search BUG https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1385, 
we need to update index manually of @IndexedEmbedded list. I intercepted the transaction and invoke manually index in afterTransactionCompletion. But it's little time consuming. It is possible to invoke index method after controller return view ?
Now is: GET -> POST -> update object -> update index (arg object) -> return list of objects
I need:  GET -> POST -> update object -> return view of objects -> update index (arg object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
public class OwnInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
       afterTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx) { 
            //implement new Thread  
        }
}
```

New thread is working async, so the controller view will be returned, meanwhile the thread will reindex data.

Answer (score 0):

Assign update index to a separate thread Or do this through JMS.

now flow will be like:

GET -> POST -> update object -> -> start new Thread to update index -> return view of objects